# Set width of all div elementes that are in same class as same

Tags: html, css

**HTML**

```css
div.section{
 /*border style code is skipped on this post*/
  background-color: #99CCFF;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: justify;
  text-justify : auto;
  overflow: hidden;

}
.topic{
 /*border style code is skipped on this post*/
}
p{
  overflow: hidden;
}

img{
  float: right;
}

div#navi{
  /*border style code is skipped on this post*/
  margin: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  color: gray;
  float: left;
}

div#navi h1{
  text-align: left;
  padding-left:10px;
}

div#navi ul{
 margin-left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="body">
    <div id="navi">
        <h1>Links</h1>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://lab.com/">Lab.</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://cse.univ.com/">CSE @ UNIV</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.w3schools.com/">W3Schools</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.csszengarden.com/"> Garden</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
        <h2><span class="topic">Cars</span>: 67 Shelby Mustang GT500 Convertible</h2>
        <p>
            <img src="67eleanorConv.jpg" alt="1967 shelby Mustang GT500 Convertible" title="1967 shelby Mustang GT500 Convertible" /> something..something..something..something..
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
        <h2><span class="topic">Sports</span>: Snowboarding</h2>
        <p>
            <img src="daaa.jpg" alt="Travis Rice Snowboard Jump" title="Travis Rice Snowboard Jump" /> something..something..something..something..something..
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
        <h2><span class="topic">Music</span>: Funk &amp; Punk Rock</h2>
        <p>
            <img src="lesPaulBass.jpg" alt="Gibson Les Paul Bass" title="Gibson Les Paul Bass" /> something..something..something..something..
            <br/>
            <br/> something..something..something..something..
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Code is so long,so i delete the part of border style in css.
I wrap div(id=nav) and div(id=section) into div(id=body)
I set a size of div that is at left side of nav div using "overflow="hidden".
but I can't set others.
The layout with a second column must still be a liquid layout -- that is, all parts of it should adjust in size accordingly when the browser size changes.
Here I post the link to the things I have and i want to:

[Result that I wanna make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QgTa.png)

[image]

[Current result of mine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AucVd.png)
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your solution should be to set the navbar to absolute positioning. so that it will always extend the full height of the parent. Then you need to set `position:relative` to the parent `div#body`, Finally, the sections need to be adjusted to offset the navbar, so I do this by adding the CSS property `margin-left:220px`.

**CSS:**

```
div#navi {
  /*border style code is skipped on this post*/
  margin: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  color: gray;
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  bottom:0px;
}

div#body {
  position:relative;
}

div.section {
  /*border style code is skipped on this post*/
  background-color: #99CCFF;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: justify;
  text-justify: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
    margin-left:220px;
}
```

---

```css
div#body {
  position:relative;
}

div.section {
  /*border style code is skipped on this post*/
  background-color: #99CCFF;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: justify;
  text-justify: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
    margin-left:220px;
}

.topic {
  /*border style code is skipped on this post*/
}

p {
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  float: right;
}

div#navi {
  /*border style code is skipped on this post*/
  margin: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  color: gray;
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  bottom:0px;
}

div#navi h1 {
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

div#navi ul {
  margin-left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="body">
  <div id="navi">
    <h1>Links</h1>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://lab.com/">Lab.</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://cse.univ.com/">CSE @ UNIV</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.w3schools.com/">W3Schools</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.csszengarden.com/"> Garden</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="section">
    <h2><span class="topic">Cars</span>: 67 Shelby Mustang GT500 Convertible</h2>

    <p>
      <img src="67eleanorConv.jpg" alt="1967 shelby Mustang GT500 Convertible" title="1967 shelby Mustang GT500 Convertible" /> something..something..something..something..
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="section">
    <h2><span class="topic">Sports</span>: Snowboarding</h2>


    <p>
      <img src="daaa.jpg" alt="Travis Rice Snowboard Jump" title="Travis Rice Snowboard Jump" /> something..something..something..something..something..
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="section">
    <h2><span class="topic">Music</span>: Funk &amp; Punk Rock</h2>
    <p>
      <img src="lesPaulBass.jpg" alt="Gibson Les Paul Bass" title="Gibson Les Paul Bass" /> something..something..something..something..
      <br/>
      <br/> something..something..something..something..
    </p>
  </div>
```

---

Comment: Maybe,I undestand logic of your answer.,but it doesn't work.  The reason why it doesn't work seems that 100% height of #navi doesn't make the height to 100%.

Comment: @gunmuk can you replicate the issue with my code showing the error.  I will try to solve!

Comment: I do not know if I understood it properly.

Comment: div#navi {
    /*border style code is skipped on this post*/
    margin: 5px;
    width: 200px;
    color: gray;
    float: left;
    height:100%;
  }

Comment: @gunmuk Updated my answer and check your mail

Comment: Then, there is no need to give override='hidden' property to section part, isn't it?

Comment: @gunmuk Yes you can remove that!